# How to calculate the max string length value in excel sheet cell range using openpyxl?

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I have tried so many different ways to calculate the max string length value in range of cells that have string values. The goal is to get the max string length and then set each column width to this max string length. The code below is implemented after string values are entered in to the range of cells but some rows will not have any values entered in. The code I have is suppose to skip any row if it's first cell value isn't a string. The values I enter into the excel range goes beyond the first cell so I just have to check value of each row's first cell to know that row doesn't have any values. I have tried to use **iter_rows()** and **iter_cols()** in ways similar to online examples to accomplish this but I haven't been able to find a solution. The error I'm getting is **for index in range(len(col)): TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()**. The module I'm using is **openpyxl** and I have set **data_only = True** within my load_workbook statement. Also, **col** is referencing a list that contains the letters of alphabet up to the last column that has any values.

Can anyone help or give me any suggestions?

```
    maxLen = 0
    for row in range(1, ws.max_row):
        if type(ws.cell(row, 1).value) == str:

            for col in range(1, ws.max_column - 1):
                if len(ws.cell(row, col).value) > len(ws.cell(row, col + 1).value):
                    maxLen = len(ws.cell(row, col).value)
                else:
                    maxLen = len(ws.cell(row, col + 1).value)
        else:
            continue

    for index in range(len(col)):
        ws.column_dimensions[f'{col[index]}'].width = maxLen
```

Comment: The looping doesn't make a lot of sense and looks likely to cause errors. `ws.iter_cols()` is the way to go for this. You just need to check the datatype of the cell before `len()`.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has this weird calculation it forces you to do between pixels and points if you're looking to be that precise, and there are functions on here to do that conversion for you but if you want to make the columns fit an entire string there is a shorter way.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ws as Worksheet : set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Columns("A:Z").Autofit

End Sub
```

You could create an excel [template file](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#loading-from-a-file) with this sub in it that openpyxl uses when creating new files.

```
wb = load_workbook('template.xltm', keep_vba=True)
wb.save('new_document.xlsm')
```

Comment: Is that method buried deep within openpyxl docs? I have never seen that before till you mentioned it

Comment: No sorry that is vba in excel, that would fire when the workbook is opened by anyone.  You could create an excel template for openpyxl to use when creating new files with this sub in it.

Comment: The other option is to use `win32com` or `xlwings` to actually open the workbook in Excel, and programmatically `AutoFit`.